# IPython Configurable with custom class

Tags: python, ipython

I'm trying to use the IPython configuration system to provide configuration parameters for my own class. I tried a simple test.

```py
from IPython.config.configurable import Configurable
from IPython.utils.traitlets import Int, Unicode, Bool

class MyConfigTest(Configurable):
    user_name = Unicode(u'Fred', config=True)

    def __init__(self, config=None):
        super(MyConfigTest, self).__init__(config=config)

    def display(self):
        print 'my name is ' + self.user_name
```

And then put this in my config file:

```
c.MyConfigTest.user_name = 'John'
```

When I run IPython --debug I can see that my config variable is being read properly:

```
[TerminalIPythonApp] Config changed:
[TerminalIPythonApp] {'MyConfigTest': {'user_name': 'John'}, 'TerminalIPythonApp
': {'log_level': 10}}
```

But when I instantiate `MyConfigTest` in my code it still has the default value:

```
In [1]: x = MyConfigTest()

In [2]: x
Out[2]: <__main__.MyConfigTest at 0x2e1dc50>

In [3]: x.display()
my name is Fred
```

Am I reading in the variable incorrectly? I read through some of the IPython source and I can't see anything obvious.

Answer (score 1):

The config system creates a config object, which is passed in when classes are instantiated, to configure them. If you want to use it within IPython, you could do it like this:

```
x = MyConfigTest(config=get_ipython().config)
```

We don't really intend this system for configuring user objects inside IPython, though. It's possible, but not a use case that the config system is designed for. It *is* designed for configuring classes in IPython extensions, and to be sufficiently general that you can use it for entirely separate applications (by subclassing `IPython.config.application.Application`).